# Easiest way to calculate $\oint_C \cos(z) dz$ with $C \equiv |z| = 1$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I would like to calculate the following integral in $\mathbb{C}$:

$$\oint_C \cos(z) dz$$

with $C \equiv |z| = 1$. One way to do that would be posing $C(\theta) = e^{i\theta}$ for $0 < \theta \le 2 \pi$:

$$= \int_0^{2\pi} \cos(e^{i\theta}).ie^{i\theta}$$

Another way would be using the first Cauchy's formula:

$$2\pi i \cos(0) = 2\pi i = \oint_C \frac{\cos(z)}{z} dz$$

Both are quite complicated. Would you know a faster way to calculate this integral ?

---

**EDIT:** I mixed up Cauchy-Goursat and Cauchy's formulas, just changed that mistake in my question (by the way, wouldn't this integral equal to zero actually ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way? The contour is closed, and the cosine is entire. By Cauchy-Goursat's theorem or some other topological method, the integral must be zero.

Another easy way: the cosine has an antiderivative, sine. You can then observe with Riemann integration theory that: $$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(e^{it})\cdot(ie^{it})\,\mathrm{d}t=\sin(e^{it})\Big|_0^{2\pi}=0$$

In the most general case, e.g. a meromorphic function with some horrendous un-computable antiderivative, if the contour is not closed then in some special cases we *adjoin new contours*, to close it up, compute the value with the residue theorem, and then say that the error term from the adjoined contours vanishes in the limit (or, we just estimate them and state an approximate (asymptotic) value). This is how complex integration theory is typically applied in real analysis, myriad examples of which can be found on this site. This tends only to work for integration on $[0,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,\infty)$ (or an  improper integrals which can be substituted into the $[0,\infty),(-\infty,\infty)$ forms) but can be applied in less common cases to integrals on $[a,b]$ if the integrand exhibits a special symmetry (often a trigonometric function, with $[a,b]=[0,\pi/2]$ or something like that).

Comment: Ok, that was as simple as that

Comment: What if the contour wasn't closed ? No shortcuts then I guess ?

Comment: @AlbertSchrödinberg In this instance (see my edit) you could just use the antiderivative

Comment: @AlbertSchrödinberg And (see my *new* edit!) we can still do well in certain special cases of non-closed contours